# Find UIPageControl Width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol

I want to place two buttons (Next and Previous) before and after `UIPageControl`. For that I need to get the current width of `UIPageControl`. How will I get the correct width as it changes based on the number of pages?

Is there any other way that I can achieve the same?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? That would make it very very easy as you wouldn't have to do anything. Also, `UIPageControl` has built in **previous** and **next** on tap, you don't need to (and shouldn't) add your own buttons to do this.

Comment: [`sizeForNumberOfPages:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uipagecontrol_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006781-CH3-SW4) seems promising...

Comment: @zach Are you linking `UIPagecontrol` to `UIScrollview`

Comment: @KananVora If you are to edit a question/answer, take the time to do it entirely, to not just markdown code class while other things can be improved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A `UIPageControl` has intrinsic size, so you can use `NSLayoutConstraint` (autolayout) to position buttons on its side.
Also, `UIPageControl` already offers a next/previous page behavior, just attach a selector to it for `UIControlEventValueChanged`